# Having trouble accessing values from json_decode

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I have a json object from a curl get request.

```
// Curl Stuff
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
{"food": {"id":585897,"foodGroup":"meats","calories":1109,"foodTier":30}}
```

I saved it in a variable with `json_decode`

```
$data = json_decode($resp, TRUE);
```

I've tried accessing the data in a couple ways but I get no response

```
echo $data[0][1];
echo $data[0]['id'];
```

Also if someone can point me in the right direction of looping through this data I would appreciate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the true parameter in your json_decode, you have associative array, so it must be:

```
echo $data['food']['id'];
```

Get the id by numeric:

```
$da = array();
foreach($data as $key=>$val){
  $da[$key] = array_values($val);
}
print_r($da);

echo $da['food'][0];
```

Comment: Is there a way to access the first parameter with number notation?

Comment: How so? I tried taking off the `TRUE` parameter and I get an error stating `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`